# Can't generate first network sample (failed storing private key)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i'm following this tutorial : http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html with windows 7
i installed all requirement but when i use this command :

```
./byfn.sh -m generate
```

I get this error :

```
##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
org1.example.com
2018-03-06 11:14:37.016 CET [bccsp_sw] storePrivateKey -> ERRO 001 Failed             
storing private key 
[5bd9c88973f78e8b0216c647887bae50d1e11f0632cb21384698843ddb4870ea]: [open 
crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\peers\peer0.org1.example.com\msp\keystore\5bd9c88973f78e8b0216c647887bae50d1e11f0632cb21384698843ddb4870ea_sk: Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.]
Error generating local MSP for {peer0 peer0.org1.example.com       [peer0.org1.example.com peer0]}:
Failed storing key [ECDSAP256]: Failed storing ECDSA private key [open crypto-config\peerOrganizations\org1.example.com\peers\peer0.org1.example.com\msp\keystore\5bd9c88973f78e8b0216c647887bae50d1e11f0632cb21384698843ddb4870ea_sk: Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.]
Failed to generate certificates...
```

It tell me that the specified path cannot be found.
Any idea what is the reason of this error ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by downloading the latest version of the binaries (v1.1.0-alpha ->v1.0.6).

Answer (score 0):

In my case directories had too long path names. Shorting them solved the problem.